# Correct usage of I've

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

Understandably "I've" is a very versatile conjunction, however I have found it being used increasingly more as a possessive.  I think in proper English this is unacceptable, but not so sure now that I am seeing it more and more.

How I imagine "I've" should be used:

> I've been dreading this all day.

Vs

> I've a large garage attached to my house.

Please tell me that my assumption is correct, and that the latter usage is incorrect?  Or is it a matter of — It's not exactly proper English, but it's acceptable (like the word "aint").

Comment: Please. "I've" is not a conjunction; it is a contraction. The Brits use "I've an x" all the time for possession and it's **perfectly** acceptable. This question should be posted on ELL, not here.

Comment: In American English, _have_ meaning 'possess' and _have_ the auxiliary verb follow different rules. Only the auxiliary _have_ is contracted; so _I've a car_ is acceptable in the US only if it's delivered in an RP accent. _I've a car reserved_ is OK because auxiliary.

Comment: @JohnLawler Were you trying to distinguish between *I've reserved a car* and *I've a car reserved* in American English?

Comment: No; they're both grammatical, though they don't mean the same.

Comment: @JohnLawler *only if it's delivered in an RP accent* -- This was exactly the point of the question.  So then, while it's *technically correct*, it's just not *acceptable* in the US?

Comment: If you say it in American accent, it will be considered odd, like _thou_. Using a word or construction that falutes significantly higher or lower than those around it draws attention to the speech and its speaker instead of its meaning.

Comment: Americans aren't likely to say "One does what one can" or "I shall not" or "I've a song in my heart," but it's OK if they do. For that matter, what's formal and correct (e.g. "Who's conning whom?") can sound funnier than a common less correct usage ("Who's conning who?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every dictionary I can find simply lists "I've" as a contraction for "I have." I don't think they specify whether "I have a large garage" can be so contracted because it hadn't occurred to them. I was able to find [one page](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/grammar/contractions-have/) showing some examples of "I've" in this latter sense.

> In American English, has is not usually contracted with a subject when it is the main verb in a sentence.

> uncontracted (common) /     contracted (not common)

> I have a blue car. /   I’ve a blue car.

> We have good news. / We’ve good news.

FWIW, it's interesting you can't do this with "has": "He has a cupcake" can't be contracted to "He's a cupcake" -- for obvious reasons!

Comment: It's funny you mentioned "has", because that's the exact reason I asked!  I thought, well, that's strange.  But English is full of those rules that apply here, but not there ...  Thank you for the clarification!